# How to close native Camera automatically, after capturing a photo using camera

Tags: android, camera, cordova

After capturing a photo using camera,

How to close native Camera automatically and redirect to app, without showing a preview with save or discard options .

Is this possible with Phonegap API?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 0):

[navigator.camera.getPicture( cameraSuccess, cameraError, [ cameraOptions ] );
Description](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture)

Function camera.getPicture opens the device's default camera application so that the user can take a picture (if Camera.sourceType = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, which is the default).

> Once the photo is taken, the camera application **closes** and your
>   application is restored.

Comment: I used this code to make default sourceType, 
`navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { 
       quality: 50,
       sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
      });`

Even I am tried without sourceType option. but same result, its showing preview. my code is below:


I am not getting, where the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As preview is part of the native app, there is no way to skip it.  :-(